# On a Mac how to determine a user logout is occuring

Tags: objective-c, macos, shutdown, logoff

I am very new to the Mac platform and Objective-C in general and in my application I would like to know how to determine that a user is logging out and perform some actions prior to this.  Any info or pointers for this?

Answer (score 3):

The official way to put the hook at logging in / logging out is described in these Apple documents [Customizing Login and Logout](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Articles/CustomLogin.html) and [Tech Note 2228](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/technotes/tn2008/tn2228.html). But I'm afraid that the log-out hook was no longer directly supported.

So, the second best way is to run a headless Cocoa app, and receive a notification from the system using `NSWorkspace`, see [the document](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Workspace/Articles/WorkspaceNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001009-CJBHEFEC) and [the  list of available notifications](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000391-BCIEFIDI).

To make a headless Cocoa app, you need to set an entry in its `Info.plist` called `LSUIElement`, see [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/LaunchServicesConcepts/LSCConcepts/LSCConcepts.html). By setting `LSUIElement` to be yes, the app don't appear in the dock, but perform various operation in the background.

Comment: Why does it need to be headless? It works just as well for a regular app.

Comment: I thought the original poster wants to detect the logging out in general. I couldn't think of any situation in a standard GUI app where I need to distinguish being quit (`applicationWillTerminate:`) and being logged out. I guess I misread.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Receiving Workspace Notifications in [this Workspace Services document](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Workspace/introduction.html).

> **NSWorkspaceWillPowerOffNotification**
>
> Posted when the user has requested a
>   logout or that the machine be powered
>   off.